# How is configuration read in AKKA

Tags: java, maven, configuration, akka

I am creating custom configurations for my akka application written in java as follows

application.conf

```
akka {
  actor {
    debug {
      # enable DEBUG logging of actor lifecycle changes
      lifecycle = on
    }
  }
}
```

I am not sure how to load this configuration. It is unclear from the docs if this needs to be explicitly loaded at actrSystem creation or if it needs to be in the class path while running the jar. In both cases, is there an example I can look at

This is a maven project and the configuration file is under src/main/resources

I see that the applucation.conf exists under target/classes. Is that it?

Comment: Thanks, when i load this, where do i see the lifecycle logs for actors ? is there any configuration needed fir each actor ?

Comment: Look here http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/java/logging.html

Answer (score 4):

With ConfigFactory you can load the **application.conf** file from      *src/main/resources*, not necessarily need an ActorSystem to use it

According to the akka doc  http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/general/configuration.html

- Akka uses the Typesafe Config Library, which might also be a good choice for the configuration of your own application or library built with or without Akka. This library is implemented in Java with no external dependencies; you should have a look at its documentation (in particular about ConfigFactory), which is only summarized in the following.

A simple test

```
import com.typesafe.config.Config;
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory;

public class ConfigFactoryTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Config conf = ConfigFactory.load("application.conf");
        System.out.println(conf.getString("akka.actor.debug.lifecycle")); //should be 'on'
     }
}
```

Also can use `withFallback` method 
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/general/configuration.html#Reading_configuration_from_a_custom_location

Assume you have another properties file called `fallback.conf`

```
akka {
 actor {
    fallback = "fallback"
       }
}

Config fallback = ConfigFactory.load("fallback.conf")
Config conf = ConfigFactory.load("application.conf").withFallback(fallback);
        System.out.println(conf.getString("akka.actor.fallback")); //fallback
```

Here you can find examples :

https://github.com/typesafehub/config/tree/master/examples/java